# Advanced Custom field loop images

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to show the loop inside Advanced custom field. This code return only the first image.

```
 <?php if( have_rows('colors') ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php while( have_rows('colors') ): the_row(); ?>

    <?php   $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('colori'), 'full'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('colors')) ?>" />

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a ACF Repeater Field you must use `get_sub_field()`, not `get_field()`. So your code should look like this:

```
<?php if( have_rows('colors') ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php while( have_rows('colors') ): the_row(); ?>

    <?php   $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('colori'), 'full'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_sub_field('colors')) ?>" />

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

It is possible that it returns false values again because I don't know how you named your ACF (repeater) sub fields.

The sub field 'colori' must be an ACF image field that outputs an ID. Not an array or something else.

`wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returns an array. `[0] => url , [1] => width, [2] => height`

Read the doc for a repeater field [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/).

Comment: Great but I don't use ACF PRO

Comment: Sorry but `have_rows()` only applies to repeater or flexible content fields of ACF (pro or premium addon)... so I thought you woulkd use the pro version...